# Error while Uploading file for API in apigee

Tags: apigee

I have an existing API proxy in Apigee edge. When I am trying to edit and save any policy I am getting below error.

```
 Error while Uploading file for API <api name>.
 org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to    com.apigee.messaging.config.beans.TargetConnection
```

I am not able to figureout how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you send us the bundle and the org name to help@apigee.com.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error message like 'cannot be cast to...' that suggests that the field is expecting a certain type (message type in your case, like a request object or response object).

Try ensuring that the variable you enter into that particular field is a message type.  It may be that the variable you are using is only a subset of a whole message.